# converting java 7 nested for loops to use java 8 streams API

Tags: java, collections, iterator, java-8, java-stream

I have an example here which basically returns list based on simple logic

Given an input list and a list of grouping objects, which has a list field, the method should return a list that contains either all the members of `grouping.list` if the `grouping.name` matches any of the strings in the input list OR simply add the input string to the returning list.

After I writing this code, I am thinking it could be made simpler in Java 7 and a better example to use Java 8 Streaming API.

```
public class CollectorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        List<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
        input.add("foo");
        input.add("bar");
        input.add("foobar");
        input.add("java");

        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        list1.add("hello");
        list1.add("world");

        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list2.add("spring");
        list2.add("multi-threaded");


        Grouping g1 = new Grouping("foobar",list1);
        Grouping g2 = new Grouping("java",list2);

        List<Grouping> groupingList = new ArrayList<>();
        groupingList.add(g1);
        groupingList.add(g2);


        System.out.println(mapAndMerge(input,groupingList));


    }


    public static List<String> mapAndMerge(List<String> input, List<Grouping> groupingList){

        Set<String> returnDocs = new HashSet<>();
        Iterator<String> it = input.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String doc = it.next();
            boolean found = false;
            for (Grouping lg : groupingList){
                if (lg.getName().equals(doc)){
                    returnDocs.addAll(lg.getList());
                    found=true;
                   }
                }
            if (!found){
                returnDocs.add(doc);
            }
        }
    return new ArrayList<>(returnDocs);
    }

}

class Grouping {

    List<String> list;
    String name;

    public Grouping(String name, List<String> list){
        this.list=list;
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }


}
```

This outputs `[spring, bar, world, foo, hello, multi-threaded]` which is correct.
Here is my Java 8 syntax that I tried and did NOT work;

```
//        List<String> mergedDocs = 
//                input.forEach(doc->
//                                 groupingList.stream().map( g -> g.getName().equals(doc) ? e.getList() : doc ).collect(Collectors.toList()));
//        return mergedDocs;
```

Comment: Please explain in your own words what the code is intended to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-write the `mapAndMerge` method following way using java 8. But it is not very concise as you like.

```
    public static List<String> mapAndMerge(List<String> input,
        List<Grouping> groupingList) {

      Set<String> returnDocs = input
        .stream()
        .map(t -> groupingList
            .stream()
            .filter(g -> g.getName().equals(t))
            .map(v -> v.getList())
            .findAny()
            .orElse(Arrays.asList(t)))
        .flatMap(t -> t.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

      return new ArrayList<>(returnDocs);
    }
```

Comment: actually it sounds better. I used boolean which I dont want to in Java 7. can you refactor the same without boolean in Java 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this *a lot* simpler by not using your `Grouping` class but using a simple `Map<String, List<String>>` instead. This map would act as the grouping, holding the list for a given name. This also enables to have a much better performance since looking into the map is constant-time (whereas your solution is in linear time since it traverses the grouping to find a matching one).

If you have to use the `List<Grouping>`, you can still pre-process it to convert into an intermediate `Map`:

The `mapAndMerge` method simply becomes:

```
public static List<String> mapAndMerge(List<String> input, List<Grouping> groupingList) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = groupingList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Grouping::getName, Grouping::getList));
    return input.stream()
                .flatMap(s -> map.getOrDefault(s, Arrays.asList(s)).stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Each input is flat mapped to the list contained in the map or a default list containing the current element. Then this is collected to a new list.  This code prints:

```
[foo, bar, hello, world, spring, multi-threaded]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be much simple and clearer if you use `Map` instead of the `Grouping` class.

So that's what you'll have in the main() method:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> groupingMap = new HashMap<>();
    groupingMap.put("foobar", list1);
    groupingMap.put("java", list2);

    List<String> mergedDocs = new ArrayList<>();
    input.stream()
         .map(doc -> groupingMap.getOrDefault(doc, Collections.singletonList(doc)))
         .forEach(mergedDocs::addAll);

    System.out.println(mergedDocs);
```